# Issue With Sound Manager Playing Random Files

Tags: java, android, touch-event

I am trying to use the SoundManager to randomly play a 30 second sound bite while simultaneously starting an animation sequence (flashing graphic) triggered by an onTouch event.  For whatever reason, the sound bite is clipped after about 5 seconds of playback and I can't figure out why.  Any thoughts?

Also after testing, it appears that the will not play until a minute or so after the initial onTouch event.

```
public class Soundboard extends Activity {
    private SoundManager mSoundManager;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        mSoundManager = new SoundManager();
        mSoundManager.initSounds(getBaseContext());
        mSoundManager.addSound(0, R.raw.sound0);
        mSoundManager.addSound(1, R.raw.sound1);
        mSoundManager.addSound(2, R.raw.sound2);
        mSoundManager.addSound(3, R.raw.sound3);
    };

    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent evt){

        Random r = new Random();
        int x = r.nextInt(3);

        switch (evt.getAction()) 
        {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            mSoundManager.playSound(x);
            startAnimating();
            return super.onTouchEvent(evt);

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            break;
            default:
            break;
        }
        return true;
    }

    private void startAnimating() {

        ImageView wiub_screen01 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.wiub_screen01);
        Animation fadein01 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.fade_in01);
        wiub_screen01.startAnimation(fadein01);

        ImageView wiub_screen00 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.wiub_screen00);
        Animation fadein00 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.fade_in00);
        wiub_screen00.startAnimation(fadein00);
    }
```

}

Comment: what are the formats of the files you are trying to play?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a good chance that the audio hasn't been loaded. If you really want to play a number of short clips, definitely look at SoundPool instead. (Adapted from Google SoundPool Example)

Try this:

```
public class Soundboard extends Activity {
    private SoundPool mSoundPool;
    boolean loaded = false;
    private int[] soundIDs;
    private int[] resIDs;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        mSoundPool = new SoundPool(10, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);
        mSoundPool.setOnLoadCompleteListener(new OnLoadCompleteListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLoadComplete(SoundPool soundPool, int sampleId,
                            int status) {
                    loaded = true;
            }
        });
        resIDs = new int[]{R.raw.sound0,R.raw.sound1,R.raw.sound2.R.raw.sound3 };

        for(int i=0; i<resIDs.length; i++){
            soundIDs[i] = mSoundPool.load(this, resIDs[i], 1);              
        }
    };

    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent evt){

        Random r = new Random();
        int x = r.nextInt(resIDs.length);

        switch (evt.getAction()) 
        {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);
                float actualVolume = (float) audioManager
                                .getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
                float maxVolume = (float) audioManager
                                .getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
                float volume = actualVolume / maxVolume;
                // Is the sound loaded already?
                if (loaded) {
                        mSoundPool.play(soundIDs[x], volume, volume, 1, 0, 1f);
                        Log.i("Test", "Played sound");
                }
            startAnimating();
            return super.onTouchEvent(evt);

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            break;
            default:
            break;
        }
        return true;
    }

    private void startAnimating() {

        ImageView wiub_screen01 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.wiub_screen01);
        Animation fadein01 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.fade_in01);
        wiub_screen01.startAnimation(fadein01);

        ImageView wiub_screen00 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.wiub_screen00);
        Animation fadein00 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.fade_in00);
        wiub_screen00.startAnimation(fadein00);
    }
}
```

Comment: Also does the length of the of the sound file matter when using AudioManager / SoundPool?  Right now my audio clips are approximately 30s but using the original AudioManager method only 5s or so would play.

Comment: I going to take a look later, but soundpool is usual for short sounds. You should definitely take a look at this in your case: http://www.stealthcopter.com/blog/2010/08/android-soundpool-vs-mediaplayer-focus-on-soundboards-and-memory-problems/

Comment: I have started changing the code to use MediaPlayer and have resolved my Null Pointer Exception issue.  I will continue to test and update code.

Comment: Switching to use MediaPlayer resolved the issues I was running into.

Answer (score 0):

Try converting the files in the raw folder to ogg format.

Comment: I'll try converting the files to .ogg before doing any code changes

Comment: I can now confirm converting to .ogg does not resolve the issue.

Comment: hmm.. I once had this for the media player it had a bug in the stage fright player. Needed to use sound track and do the decoding myself. maybe that would help you that or using soundpool.

Comment: I ended up changing the code to utilize MediaPlayer which resolved the issues I was running into.